# How to update a list item RadListView in Nativescript using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript, javascript-objects, dom-events, tns

I'm trying to build a sample application in Nativescript using Javascript. I have a RadListView where the list is populated. I've various elements in my list like name, image, description and favourites icon. Here when I click on the favourites icon I need to change the status of the icon for the particular item in the list. Can anyone please help how I can do it?

cars-list-page.js

```
function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    console.log('car list page Loaded......:');
    console.log(args.object);  
    const page = args.object;    
    page.bindingContext = new CarsListViewModel(args);   

}
```

car-view-model.js

```
    const observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");
const httpModule = require("http");
const ObservableArray = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
/* const CarService = require("./shared/car-service");  */

var uuid = require('platform').device.uuid;
console.log("uuid: "+uuid);

var viewModel = new observableModule.Observable();
viewModel.set("items", []); // initial value


function CarsListViewModel(args) {

    console.log('CarsListViewModel argsssss');
    console.dir(args.object);

    var page = args.object;

    var gotData = page.navigationContext;
    console.log(gotData.idx);
    console.log(gotData.name);
    console.log(gotData.type);

    viewModel.set('isLoading', false);
    viewModel.set('name', gotData.type);
    viewModel.set('description', gotData.name);

    var apiURL = 'urlgoeshere';

    fetch(apiURL)  
      .then(response => {
        console.log('resppppp......');   
        return response.json();   
      })
      .then(function(r) { 
        //console.log(r.data);
        viewModel.set('items', r.data);
        console.log('View Model Updated......');
        const firstItem = viewModel.getItem(0);
        console.log('View Model Updated......'+firstItem);
      });    
     return viewModel;
}  

module.exports = CarsListViewModel;
```

Comment: Add some code on what you've currently done, otherwise it's a bit difficult to help you out.

Comment: Use Observables to bind your data on the item template, when you update the data the UI gets updated automatically, more on [RadListView](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/ListView/getting-started) / [Observable](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/observable) docs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how it translates to JavaScript, but you should be using an `ObservableArray` instead of just `[]`.

Then you'll want to do `viewModel.get('items').push(...r.data)` or something similar.